# Create Route With 2 Static Literals Before Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

Ok I thought this would be straight forward but I'm missing something. I am mapping a Web API route and want it to be the following:

```
http://localhost:1234/api/myBlog/Articles
```

And thought this would work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "BlogApi",                
   url: "api/myBlog/{controller}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Articles", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

the 'myBlog' segment is not a controller or a folder. I just want it to be a part of the URL. I tried creating a folder named 'myBlog' under Controllers with the `ArticlesController` controller but that didn't make a difference. I always get a 404 not found: ***No type was found that matches the controller named 'myBlog'.***

Also odd when I do `http://localhost:1234/api/myBlog` the default controller in the route `Articles` is not used, so want to know about this too.

I can only get it to work if I do the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "BlogApi",                
   url: "api/Articles/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Articles", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and call: `http://localhost:1234/api/Articles`

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "BlogApi",                
   routeTemplate: "api/myBlog/Articles/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Articles", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and put it **before** the default route.

Comment: I actually commented out the default route (should have mentioned that) and I still get a 404 when I try this. When I inspect it in Fiddler I get the following message: *No type was found that matches the controller named 'myBlog'*

Comment: This is what VS.NET 2012 with the ASP.NET fall update RC is using by default when creating a Web API project. I din't write these from scratch but copy and paste. Are you saying `MapHttpRoute` is different from `MapRoute`?

Comment: It's the same, but web api routes are register under WebApiConfig.Register() method, if you register them under RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes() they will not be picked up as the default Web API route will be *earlier*. Register the route inside WebApiConfig.Register()

Comment: Moved it over to WebApiConfig, *before* the default route and I get the following error: *No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI http://localhost:4940/api/myBlog/Articles.","MessageDetail":"No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI*

Comment: ArticlesController exists and inherits from ApiController? Has a public Get() method?

Comment: Yes and Yes. The only way I got this to work was to *change* the `DefaultApi` route in WebApiConfig to routeTemplate: "api/myBlog/Articles/{id}". So now it's working, I hit the `Get` method, but I messed up the default route. How do I make it so I can have both. I tried creating one *before* the default route and got the error from my last comment.

Comment: I made a demo project where everything works, perhaps you can use it as reference? 1. 
http://localhost:41049/api/myblog/articles (goes to ArticlesController) 2. http://localhost:41049/api/other (goes to any other controller i.e. OtherController) https://www.dropbox.com/s/wt24ao6bcirinnz/MvcApplication4.zip

Comment: Thank you. Here are the issues it boiled down to and your help solved it: 1. Use `WebApiConfig` and not `RouteConfig`. 2. Once I added an additional route to `WebApiConfig` it did not have `controller = "Articles"` in the defaults and was second issue. I now have (2) routes (mine and default) in `WebApiConfig` and all methods are being hit from Fiddler. Thank you.